# Jasper report with 2 differents databases (Oracle and postgresql)

Tags: oracle, postgresql, jasper-reports

I'm here to ask for your help, so my probleme is:

I have created report with jasperrerport 3.7.6 (queries based on oracle).
and now I'm trying to use the same report with PostgreSql Database and I'm getting errors for specific oracle functions like (NVL, sysdate ...), and I don't want to change the query for now (unless I have to).

Is there any thing to use to make autoconversion when executed on a postgresql database?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no matching functions in both databases, consider creating your own functions which will "simulate" the originals.

For example, for Oracle's `SYSDATE`:

```
create or replace function f_sysdate return date is
begin
  return sysdate;
end;
```

I don't know PostgreSQL, but - you'd do the same in that database. Function's name **must** be the same: `F_SYSDATE`.

Then, in JasperReports, instead of calling "originals", you'd call your own functions, e.g.

```
select ename, job, sal, 
       f_sysdate              --> this
from emp
where deptno = 10
```

Doing so, report would work in both databases. True, you'd have to put some initial effort, but - it might pay off in the future.

Comment: it would help me if i could call my new functions without parentheses (in the case of sysdate), but for example the function NVL in oracle i can passe any combination of parameters type, if i create this function in postgres I have to create it multiple times to handle parameters type combinations

Comment: Well, another option is to maintain two versions of the same report: one for Oracle, another for PostgreSQL. None of these options is *perfect*; choose one that suits you better.